# Pre selecting an option in sx:autocompleter

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, struts2, dojo, struts

I have one `sx:autocompleter` dropdown and one hidden element in my JSP.

```
<sx:autocompleter list="vendorNameList" name="vendor_name"
autoComplete="false" id="vendor_name" value="%{vendor_name}"/>

<s:hidden name="vendorName" id="vName"></s:hidden>

function setSelectedIndex() {
selectionVname=dojo.widget.byId('vendor_name');
v=document.getElementById('vName').value;

for (var i = 0; i < selectionVname.options.length; i++) {
    
    if (selectionVname.options[i].text == v) {  
        
        selectionVname.options[i].selected = true;
        
        return;
        
    }
}
}
window.onload = setSelectedIndex;
```

I want this vendorName member's value to come as a pre selected value in the dropdown when the page loads. The script that I have written is not working. It is breaking before entering the **`for`** loop. I have a doubt that whether `selectionVname.options.length` is a correct way of writing the `sx:autocompleter` or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, it's not correct way, the `id` is not a HTML tag attribute, but a JSP tag attribute, and you mistreated it in the javascript code. Any way if you want to preselect the value you should use `value` attribute. The description from the docs page [`<sx:autocompleter>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/dojo-autocompleter-tag.html)

> `value`   `false`     `false` `String` Preset the value of input element

Note: the dojo plugin is deprecated since Struts 2.1.